# Include subquery in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I want to aggregate my SQL query below using GROUP BY but I am not sure how to include the inner SELECT into my GROUP BY clause. Is it somehow possible to do like `GROUP BY PEOPLE.NAME, PEOPLE.ADDRESS, CITY` ?

```
SELECT PEOPLE.NAME AS NAME,
 PEOPLE.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS,
 (SELECT PEOPLE.CITY 
  FROM ... 
  WHERE ...) AS CITY
FROM MYSCHEMA.PEOPLE PEOPLE
GROUP BY PEOPLE.NAME, PEOPLE.ADDRESS
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.NAME AS NAME, p.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS, c.CITY 
FROM MYSCHEMA.PEOPLE p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT . . .
      FROM ... 
      WHERE ...
     ) c
     ON . . . 
GROUP BY p.NAME, p.ADDRESS, c.CITY;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one more way of retrieving the result. Do a Select over it again and then apply group by:

```
SELECT NAME,ADDRESS,CITY, <Groupby Function> from 
(
 SELECT PEOPLE.NAME AS NAME,
 PEOPLE.ADDRESS AS ADDRESS,
 (SELECT PEOPLE.CITY 
  FROM ... 
  WHERE ...) AS CITY
FROM MYSCHEMA.PEOPLE PEOPLE
)
GROUP BY NAME, ADDRESS,CITY
```